# Отправка файлов на сервер по xmlhttp

Tags: xmlhttprequest

Отправляю файлы на сервер с помощью xmlhttp

JS:

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', '/or/test.php', true); 
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 


var data = new FormData();
var fp = $("#my_file");

for(var i=0, len=fp[0].files.length; i<len; i++) 
    data.append(fp[0].files[i].name, fp[0].files[i]); 

xmlhttp.send(data);
```

Интересно, что $_FILES пуст, а $_POST показывает информацию о файле. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Удалил к черту header и получилось!